# How do I remove a URL from a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, url, replace

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to remove URLs from my string so I tried this

```
puts "str before: #{my_str}"
my_str.gsub!(/#{URI::regexp}/, '')
puts "str after url sub: #{my_str}"
```

but only the "http" is getting stripped off.  Here is the output from the lines above

```
str before: Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROUP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)
str after url sub: Top (//www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROUP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)
```

What's the proper way to remove a URL from a string?

**Edit:** Here is what happend when I did 'puts "#{URI::regexp}"'

```
(?x-mi:
        ([a-zA-Z][\-+.a-zA-Z\d]*):                           (?# 1: scheme)
        (?:
           ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;?:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)                    (?# 2: opaque)
        |
           (?:(?:
             \/\/(?:
                 (?:(?:((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;:&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)@)?        (?# 3: userinfo)
                   (?:((?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-.]|%\h\h)+|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}|\[(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})|(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*[a-fA-F\d]{1,4})?::(?:(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}:)*(?:[a-fA-F\d]{1,4}|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))?)\]))(?::(\d*))?))? (?# 4: host, 5: port)
               |
                 ((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d$,;:@&=+]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})+)                 (?# 6: registry)
               )
             |
             (?!\/\/))                           (?# XXX: '\/\/' is the mark for hostport)
             (\/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*(?:\/(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*(?:;(?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d:@&=+$,]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*)*)*)?                    (?# 7: path)
           )(?:\?((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                 (?# 8: query)
        )
        (?:\#((?:[\-_.!~*'()a-zA-Z\d;\/?:@&=+$,\[\]]|%[a-fA-F\d]{2})*))?                  (?# 9: fragment)
      )
```

Comment: I just tested the same code and it removed the whole url. Ruby version: `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16]` Can you post what `URI::regexp` looks like the context of that code?

Comment: Also is there any specific reason for the regex interpolation? why not just `my_str.gsub!(URI::regexp, '')`

Comment: Sure, I included URI::regexp in my question.  Get the same result when running "my_str.gsub!(/URI::regexp, '')"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That seems to be working fine for a regular string:

```
my_str = "Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM\" \\l \"Top)"
puts "str before: #{my_str}"          # => str before: Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)    
my_str.gsub!(/#{URI::regexp}/, '')
puts "str after url sub: #{my_str}"   # => str after url sub: Top (" \l "Top)
```

But, yours might have some garbage, non-printable, characters in it. Take, for instance, a random null character right before the first slash:

```
#                   vv - random null character
my_str = "Top (http:\0//www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM\" \\l \"Top)"
#                                                looks the same vv
puts "str before: #{my_str}"          # => str before: Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)
my_str.gsub!(/#{URI::regexp}/, '')
puts "str after url sub: #{my_str}"   # => str after url sub: Top (//www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)
```

Now, if you try and copy and paste the output from this null character from the website, it will still work:

```
# I copied this from the output from the line below `looks the same vv`
my_str = 'Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)'
puts "str before: #{my_str}"          # => str before: Top (http://www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM" \l "Top)
my_str.gsub!(/#{URI::regexp}/, '')
puts "str after url sub: #{my_str}"   # => str after url sub: Top (" \l "Top)
```

So it would end up looking like it works for us. So, you might try removing all non-printable characters and see if it works for you:

```
my_str = "Top (http:\0//www.lafayettefitness.org/Results/2011%20CHASING%20THE%20RAINBEAU%205K%20AGE%20GROU;5DP%20RESULTS.HTM\" \\l \"Top)"
my_str.gsub!(/[^[:print:]]/i, '')
my_str.gsub!(/#{URI::regexp}/, '')
puts "str after url sub: #{my_str}"   # => str after url sub: Top (" \l "Top)
```

Comment: Never in a million years would I have thought of htis.  There is indeed a problematic character between teh ":" and the "/", with char.ord code = 8203 .  But the ".gsub!(/[^[:print:]]/i, '')" clause doens't seem to be removing it.  Any other strategy I should try?

Comment: I believe that's a [Zero Width Space](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm) (not entirely sure what the "ordinal value of a character" is, but the decimal UTF-16 version of that character is 8203...that page has it in the "Other, format" category, so we should be able to target it with `gsub(/\p{Cf}/, '')`

Comment: THat's a winner. Thx for your out of the box thinking